# Create a data.frame adding N rows of sampling functions

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I'm struggling trying to create a data.frame of random samples. I give a reproducible example:

I have a few custom functions similar to this:

```
vendorSelector <- function() {
  sample(c("Paco", "Juan", "Alex", "Marc"), 1)
}

productSelector <- function() {
  sample(c("Water", "Oil", "Carbon", "Wood"), 1)
}
```

I achieved to create the data frame manually doing this:

```
data <- data.frame(Vendor = vendorSelector(), Product = productSelector(),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And then repeating manually this line of code:

```
data <- rbind(data, c(Vendor = vendorSelector(), Product = productSelector()))
```

My problem is that I want to generate a data.frame of 1000 rows and I don't want to run manually 999 times the rbind chunk to achieve it. Can you help me to think some sort of loop or custom function to achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

directly sample the 1000 rows in one go, you need to set `replace=T` as the number of sampled items is bigger than the original set of items

```r
data.frame(Vendor = sample(c("Paco", "Juan", "Alex", "Marc"), 1000, replace=T), Product =  sample(c("Water", "Oil", "Carbon", "Wood"), 1000, replace=T),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, your approach to the solution gave me an idea to continue my data project and also solved the issue I was having!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your functions by including a parameter and then sample n observations:

```
productSelector <- function(n) {
  sample(c("Water", "Oil", "Carbon", "Wood"), n, replace = T)
}

vendorSelector <- function(n) {
  sample(c("Paco", "Juan", "Alex", "Marc"), n, replace = T)
}

data <- data.frame(Vendor = vendorSelector(10), Product = productSelector(10),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data

       Vendor Product
1    Paco     Oil
2    Paco  Carbon
3    Juan     Oil
4    Paco     Oil
5    Marc  Carbon
6    Juan     Oil
7    Juan  Carbon
8    Juan    Wood
9    Alex     Oil
10   Paco    Wood
```